# How can I use CSS Modules in a Nrwl NX workspace?

Tags: nrwl, nrwl-nx

I'm refactoring an old React/Webpack project to Nrwl's NX monorepo solution.
In that project css modules are used.

For example, styles are imported this way:

```
import style from './style.scss';
```

and used like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => <div className={style.root}>Hello World</div>
```

This doesn't work in NX, because `style` is an empty object at runtime, so all class names are gone in the actual output.

Is there a way to make CSS Modules work with NX?

Comment: Yes you can by extending the Webpack configuration as shown here https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1744#issuecomment-528461305